# Bash process gets killed in HPC

Tags: bash, slurm

I am new to bash scripting and I am using the below script to automate my job submission.
This scripts waits for the previous job to finish and automatically submits a new job.

```
while true 
do
        jobstat=$(squeue -u $USER | grep DNAJB6 | wc -l)

        if [[ "$jobstat" == '0' ]]; then
                sbatch per3_restart.sh
                break
        fi

done
```

I run this with `./script.sh &` on my login node

This is the output when I do `top | grep bash` for sometime (maybe a day), after that I will not see this even if i `grep` with the process ID

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
26054 vadupa    20   0  140428   3052    836 S   0.3  0.0   0:04.47 bash
```

But after sometime, the process gets automatically killed with out any error message or warning.

Am I missing something ? Lemme know, Thanks.

**Edit**:

I logout and login to frequently to check the progress.

Output for `bash -x script.sh > /tmp/trace.txt 2>&1 &`

```
+ [[ hxB =~ i ]]
+ export -f module
+ ENV=/hpc/eb/modules-tcl-1.923/init/profile.sh
+ export ENV
+ BASH_ENV=/hpc/eb/modules-tcl-1.923/init/bash
+ export BASH_ENV
+ '[' 4 -ge 3 ']'
+ [[ hxB =~ i ]]
+ MODULESHOME=/hpc/eb/modules-tcl-1.923
+ export MODULESHOME
+ [[ ! :/hpc/sw/hpc/bin:/hpc/sw/hpc/sbin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/hpc/eb/compilerwrappers/compilers:/hpc/eb/compilerwrappers/linkers:/hpc/eb/modules-tcl-1.923/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/ibutils/bin:/home/vadupa/bin: =~ :/hpc/eb/modules-tcl-1\.923/bin: ]]
++ manpath
+ manpath=/hpc/sw/hpc/man:/hpc/sw/hpc/man:/hpc/eb/modules-tcl-1.923/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man/overrides:/usr/share/man:/opt/ibutils/share/man:/hpc/sw/hpc/man:/hpc/eb/modules-tcl-1.923/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man/overrides:/usr/share/man:/opt/ibutils/share/man:/usr/share/man
+ [[ ! :/hpc/sw/hpc/man:/hpc/sw/hpc/man:/hpc/eb/modules-tcl-1.923/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man/overrides:/usr/share/man:/opt/ibutils/share/man:/hpc/sw/hpc/man:/hpc/eb/modules-tcl-1.923/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man/overrides:/usr/share/man:/opt/ibutils/share/man:/usr/share/man: =~ :/hpc/eb/modules-tcl-1\.923/share/man: ]]
+ '[' /sw/noarch/modulefiles/environment:/hpc/sw/modules/modulefiles/init:/hpc/sw/modules/modulefiles/init-devel = '' ']'
+ '[' compilerwrappers:surfsara = '' ']'
+ '[' -r /hpc/eb/modules-tcl-1.923/init/modulerc -a /sw/noarch/modulefiles/environment:/hpc/sw/modules/modulefiles/init:/hpc/sw/modules/modulefiles/init-devel = '' -a compilerwrappers:surfsara = '' ']'
+ true
++ squeue -u vadupa
++ wc -l
+ jobstat=2
+ [[ 2 == \1 ]]
```

Comment: While there may not be any error in the terminal because it's running in the background, have you looked at `sacct -j job_number`? That will give details on the job including why it failed.

Comment: @NasirRiley  sacct shows nothing with the job number of the process.  I guess, this process will not be treated as a job, as I am not asking for any cores/nodes. It normally shows in `top`, or when I do `top | grep bash`

Comment: When the condition becomes true, the `break` will terminate the loop. In this situation your script as shown in the question will end. Unrelated: To reduce the load of this busy waiting I suggest to add a delay inside the loop, e.g. `sleep 1`, maybe only in the case when you don't have to restart the job.

Comment: @Bodo Condition isn't met yet. There is a job still running with name DNAJB6

Comment: How do you know that the job is *still running* and not *running again after restart*? To debug your script you could add some code that writes to a log file, e.g. `echo restarting job >> /tmp/log.txt` or `echo after loop >> /tmp/log.txt` or run it with `bash -x script.sh > /tmp/trace.txt 2>&1 &` (This may create many lines of output especially without a delay in the loop.) Can you confirm that you don't log out and log in again? Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification.

Comment: @Bodo I do logout and login frequently. I will try with the `bash -x ...`

Comment: When you log out then your script may get killed by a `SIGHUP`. Start it with `nohup ./script.sh &` to avoid this. **Please [edit] your question** to add requested information or clarification, don't use comments to add information.

Comment: Also, if this is an HPC login node, an admin might be cleaning up user processes after they log out.  When I was an HPC admin we strictly enforced the “no jobs running on login nodes” policy by killing user processes similar to yours.

Comment: is there any particular reason WHY you're doing that?  why not just submit all the jobs you need to run and let slurm figure out when to run them? That's slurm's job, after all.   BTW, if some or all of your jobs are dependent on the output of previous jobs then you need to write the job scripts to take that into account.   Also, is `sbatch` installed on the compute nodes or only on the login nodes? if it is on the compute nodes, you can submit a job that starts other jobs.

Comment: @cas yes, the output of one job Is required to do the next job.  Can I know more on how to include this in a job script.  I am not sure whether `sbatch` is included in the login/compute nodes. Is there any way, I could get that information from a command?

Comment: 1. an sbatch script is just a shell script (bash is you give it a #!/bin/bash shebang line) so just run one command in it, then the next, same as you would in any other shell script.   If there's any chance that multiple identical jobs may run at the same time, you'll need to make sure they don't interfere with each other.  Tell the first command in the batch job to store it's output in a specific file (e.g. to `"$HOME/$SLURM_JOB_ID-stage1.out"`) and then tell the second command to read its input from that file and output to, e.g., `"$HOME/$SLURM_JOB_ID-stage2.out"`.  Always quote variables.

Comment: 2. To find out if `sbatch` is installed on the compute nodes, either check the documentation/ask the sysadmins of your cluster or run a sbatch job which runs `command -v sbatch` (this will output the full path to sbatch if it's installed and in $PATH, or return an exit code of 1 with no output if it isn't).   IMO, it's better to ask the sysadmins because it's possible (but unlikely) that it may be installed on some but not all compute nodes.    And even better to write your scripts so that you don't need to run sbatch from within them.